# Calling a javascript method from android

Tags: javascript, android, string, function

I have following method to be called from android. I have written it as follows but control is not entering into javascript. Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

```
String resp = javascript:httpservicesuccess("{\"code\":\"200\",\"requestID\":\"1000\",\"body\":\"{\"units\":{\"temperature\":\"C\",\"speed\":\"km\/h\",\"distance\":\"km\",\"pressure\":\"mb\"},\"location\":{\"location_id\":\"ITXX0024\",\"city\":\"Como\",\"state_abbreviation\":\"*\",\"country_abbreviation\":\"IT\",\"elevation\":935,\"latitude\":45.81000000000000,\"longitude\":9.08000000000000},\"wind\":{\"speed\":5.00000000000000,\"direction\":\"S\"},\"atmosphere\":{\"humidity\":\"47\",\"visibility\":9.99000000000000,\"pressure\":1016.00000000000000,\"rising\":\"steady\"},\"url\":\"http:\/\/weather.yahoo.com\/forecast\/ITXX0024.html\",\"logo\":\"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/a\/i\/us\/nt\/ma\/ma_nws-we_1.gif\",\"astronomy\":{\"sunrise\":\"06:47\",\"sunset\":\"18:22\"},\"condition\":{\"text\":\"Fair\",\"code\":\"34\",\"image\":\"http:\/\/l.yimg.com\/a\/i\/us\/we\/52\/34.gif\",\"temperature\":10.00000000000000},\"forecast\":[{\"day\":\"Today\",\"condition\":\"Sunny\",\"high_temperature\":13.00000000000000,\"low_temperature\":3.00000000000000},{\"day\":\"Tomorrow\",\"condition\":\"Partly Cloudy\",\"high_temperature\":14.00000000000000,\"low_temperature\":5.00000000000000}]}\",\"headers\":{"Date":"Mon, 23 Apr 2012 03:50:41 GMT","Cache-Control":"public, max-age=1800","Expires":"Mon, 23 Apr 2012 04:20:41 GMT","Connection":"close","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}}")  
webView.loadUrl(resp);
```

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Where are you calling it from inside the android? in the browser somewhere? I am a little ignorant to how this would work, but I do have an android that I can test things on.

Comment: It's in android Activity. I wanted to enquire if the way i am calling the method is right or wrong? i never used parameterized function calls of javascript. So..

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Use it this way. It's not a URL, but its a HTML string.

```
webview.loadData(resp, "text/html", null);
```

Edit - Use the right format (I am not sure if text/html is right). But that's how you load the data.